# Please explain the difference between 具備, 俱備

Tags: meaning

Please explain the difference between 具備, 俱備. Do they mean the same thing? Or is there some subtle differences? To me they both seem to mean the exact same thing: to be prepared. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- [**具備**](具-equipped + 備-prepared) is a compound word verb that means "possess/ equipped with"

Example: **具備**先進武器 (**Equipped with** advanced weapons); **具備**豐富資源 (**Possess** abundant resources)

- [俱][備](all are ready) are two words:  俱(all) + 備(prepared)

Example: Idiom: 萬事俱備 (everything is ready); 人馬糧草俱備 (personnel and supplies are all prepared)